# Fix a CSS problem with a Wordpress theme and a syntax highlighting plugin

Tags: css, xhtml

I installed the latest version of Wordpress and added the [WP-Syntax](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/) plugin (and also the [Markdown Extra](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/) plugin, but I think it's unrelated to this issue).

It works perfectly with both themes that ship with Wordpress: [looking good using WordPress Default 1.6](https://imgur.com/tEPSe.png) and [looking equally good with the WordPress Classic 1.5](https://imgur.com/IOoYG.png) theme.

However it doesn't work with the excellent [LightWord](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/lightword) theme, which I would like to use. The code box looks strange with the right border at the end of the actual code:

[image]

**My thoughts:**

I have tried investigating this with Firebug without any success. The CSS from the WP-Syntax plugin should be the same in all three theme cases. So the fact that it looks wierd with this theme has to do with some inherited CSS property from the LightWord theme.

This in turn probably means that the WP-Syntax plugin should reset something more for its CSS to work correctly.

**Help!**

Advanced CSS isn't something I'm good at. But I would very much like to resolve this problem as soon as possible. I'm also curious from a technical view point what could be causing this behavior? I hope someone with good CSS skills will be able to help out!

We (you if you want to, me if you don't feel like it) could then file a bug report in the appropriate place, to get these components working together.

To resolve this I understand you need more than screenshots. I have a link with the problem theme, which could be used to investigate further.

**Web site where the problem may be experienced** (Taken down as the problem is solved)

**Edit:** In response to a comment I'm also including a link to the working web site using the classic theme and the same plugin setup: **Link to a working theme with these plugins** (Taken down as the problem is solved)

Thank you for reading!

### Summary of problems I'd like to solve:

- What's the best way to get rid of the right and bottom inner border in the code box? I first noticed the right border, but the bottom border is also an eye sore.
- The code box right border isn't visible. It's due to `.wp_syntax {width:100%;}` and if I set it to 99% it's visible again. Do you consider this to be a problem with the theme or the plugin?
- Making changes in the theme (style.css) *or* the plugin (wp-syntax.css) would be preferred if that's possible, so one of them could be standard. But which one? And how?

Comment: If you provide a link to a web page with one of the themes that works, and not just an image, it'll be possible to see what differences in the markup are contributing to this.

Comment: I didn't think it would provide much added value. My reasoning was that the default themes are complex, and that solving the problem my looking at similarities/differences would be the wrong way to take. Also I only have only blog installed. I'll think about it for next time though! It seems someone was able to solve it anyway this time.

Comment: On second thought I'm including a working site. The way I did it was using wget to download the site using the two themes, one working and one non-working. Unfortunately not all files were included, but enough was, the problem is there in one and not in the other. And the CSS-files are intact. I hope it helps.

Comment: I also added a problem summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems you are having are due to the stylesheets of WP-Syntax and LightWord interfering with each other. I don't really think that the problems are with the theme or the plugin, they are just down to how the two interact with each other.

To make all of the required changes, ideally you would edit styles in both [wp-syntax.css](http://kentlarsson.eu/lightword-problem/wp-syntax.css) and [style.css](http://kentlarsson.eu/blog/wp-content/themes/lightword/style.css). You can however cheat a little.

In **style.css** add the following:

```
.wp_syntax { width:auto; }
```

.wp_syntax table { border:0 !important; }

.wp_syntax table td { border:0 !important; }

These changes should solve all of the problems, with the benefit of keeping all of the changes localised to a single file (style.css of the LightWood theme). The other tables in the example should all remain unchanged as well.

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to have any suggestion to the problems described in the problem summary? I'm uncertain of how to remedy these problems.

Comment: Upvoted as you're taking us closer to the solution. But we're not there yet I'm afraid.

Comment: See my edited answer above with the response to your question edit.

Comment: Thank you again for trying to help me! And of course you do! Still, those changes messed up the tables for the theme: 
http://imgur.com/chyJa.png I would really like them to look as they did if that is possible. I'll look more at this tomorrow. I'd like to be able to have the two removed border styles for normal tables (not the Geshi generated table). There must be a way.. hm.. Anwyay, thanks SO much for your help so far! It's greatly appreciated!

Comment: So they did. Hadn't spotted that. See my edited answer again.